# Is it bad to check for IE with PHP

Tags: php, internet-explorer, if-statement

I'm setting up a check for IE in a wordpress theme I am developing. I wanted to check for Internet Explorer 7. So if I use the following code:

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/\bmsie 7/i', $ua) && !preg_match('/\bopera/i', $ua))
echo 'Do Something' 
?>
```

Instead of:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
Do Something
<![endif]-->
```

Is there any drawbacks to it? Just trying to load HTML only when it is needed. Any insight is appreciated.

EDIT

Found this really good article on doing it the PHP way: http://www.kingofdevelopers.com/php-classes/get-browser-name-version.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try detect the platform, the engine and the version, that cover a lot of possible browsers and let me code based on that, for example, the engine gecko, covers firefox, seamonkey and all the gecko based browsers.

in php use the

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

Comment: get_browser() uses browscap.ini which is part of the Browser Capabilities Project, which unfortunately is currently closed. It would be best to not use this function until it can be made certain that the project will be re-opened.

Comment: @cryptic could you give me link [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) there is no warning

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/browscap/Yy3Djd1Mqvk
http://browsers.garykeith.com/
https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap/issues/24

Comment: It just recently happened, so PHP docs won't be reflecting it as of yet. The official download page is in the PHP docs, visiting it will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Both are right. The second way is client side, which would be beneficial if you use some common activity such as - including SVG specific elements, IE Specific stylesheet etc), you would reduce server side processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with user1759084, they are both "right" but I would add that it depends on how much HTML your are delivering. If it is a considerably amount it makes more sense to check on the server (php check), if it is just a couple of lines, it's probably better to let the client decide (HTML conditional). You really should be using feature detection instead of browser detection, but there are some cases when that just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this class of php. thats detected exactly
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2525-PHP-Detect-the-browser-type-and-capabilities-category.html